# Picking only the first value equals 1 in time period

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, analytics

I have the df which has index with dates and values 0 or 1. I need to filter every first 1 from this data frame in several time periods
For example:

```
date            val  ind
2019-08-12        0  0
2019-08-13        1  0
2019-08-14        1  0
2019-08-15        0  1
2019-08-16        1  0
2019-08-19        1  0
2019-08-20        0  0
2019-08-21        1  0
2019-08-22        1  1
2019-08-23        1  0
2019-08-26        0  0
2019-08-27        1  0
2019-08-28        1  0
2019-08-29        0  1
2019-08-30        0  0
```

Each 1 in df['ind'] means the beginning of time period.
Now I'm interested to get the first 1 in each time period:

```
2019-08-16        1  0
2019-08-22        1  1
```

Comment: How do we know where the periods start?

Comment: What qualifies as a period? In your exemple the second one should come at 2020-06-03 and not 2020-06-04 unless there's something I missed ?

Comment: I demonstrated only the part of my df. I also have the column with the values 0 or 1 where 1 means the beginning of the period

Answer (score 0):

you could try something that counts up the amount of 1's and restarts when it hits a 0 and saves the index of that next 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the first "1" of each group of ones.

See with a dataframe like :

```
       dates  val
0 2019-11-29    0
1 2019-12-02    0
2 2019-12-03    1
3 2019-12-04    1
4 2019-12-05    1
5 2020-06-01    0
6 2020-06-02    0
7 2020-06-03    1
8 2020-06-04    1
9 2020-06-05    1


mask = df["val"].ne(df["val"].shift(1)) & df["val"].eq(1)
df.loc[mask]
```

Gets you:

```
       dates  val
2 2019-12-03    1
7 2020-06-03    1
```

We get this by shifting the dataframe a step forward and checking for differences. This means that any row where the current row is different from the current row will be matched : the cases where 1 is the value and 0 is the previous value or where 0 is the value and 1 is the previous value.

Then, we add the other condition that the current row must be equal to 1, which gets each row where a 1 first appears when preceded by a 0.

Comment: All I need is to pick every first 1 inside the time period. The period could contain several groups of ones, but I need to find only the first

Comment: @ДаниилАлтухов Can you please explain what you expect in more details? What's the issue with my answer?

Comment: As I understand your code helps to find the first value in every group of ones. As I have already written I have another column (df['ind']) with values 0 or 1. One means the beginning of time period. I need to find the first 1 in every time period of my df. Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: @ДаниилАлтухов But you didn't provide an example using the values and `df["ind"]`, if we don't have all the information, we can't help you

Comment: I've updated the information, I'm newbie on stackoverflow, sorry for that